# android: remove a row from the tablelayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, layout-inflater

for adding a row in a tablelayout, the code can be done as follows:

```
   private void ToDisplayTagGUI(String Slot, int index)
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tag_view, null);
      SlotTableLayout.addView(newTagView, index);
```

for removing the whole tablelayout's data, the code can be as follows:

```
      SlotTableLayout.removeAllViews();
```

how could i do so if i just want to remove one of the rows from the tablelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove particular row from tablelayout you can use :

table.removeView(rowindex);